# Issue with installing odoo (open ERP 8) module

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I have installed [Odoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odoo) 8.0 (OpenERP 8.0) on a digital ocean droplet. Now when I try to install any module (application), I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 525, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 562, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 302, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 299, in checked_call
return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 791, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 395, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 953, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 941, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 498, in _button_immediate_function
registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 346, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 363, in load_modules
loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 263, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 149, in load_module_graph
load_openerp_module(package.name)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 314, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 79, in load_module
mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
File "/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0/travel/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from . import (
File "/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0/travel/travel_passenger.py", line 27, in <module>
class travel_passenger(orm.Model):
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/models.py", line 253, in __init__
setattr(self, name, column.to_field())
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 161, in to_field
return Field.by_type[self._type](**self.to_field_args())
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1305, in to_field_args
args['selection'] = self.selection
AttributeError: 'related' object has no attribute 'selection'
```

I think there are some problems with the configuration when I set up in Odoo. I used some scripts from *[OpenERP Install Scripts](https://github.com/aschenkels-ictstudio/openerp-install-scripts)* (at [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)). How do I get out of this situation?

Comment: Do you have any custom module related to "Travelling". It looks like, system is facing problem while importing "tarvel_passenger.py" file. If possible post code of that file here.

Comment: No, i am having same error when i try to install any module. So i do not think it is the problem with the module code.

Comment: can you post the code of that module of "Travelling" here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have broken module called 'travel' which blocks any other update operation.
So you need to either fix or disable that module.
Please use below sql query on PgAdmin.
*update ir_module_module set state='uninstalled' where name='travel'*

I'm not sure if above name of module is correct. If above query doesn't work then change 'travel' to correct term.